# Using nleqslv: function contains non-finite values

Tags: r

I want to get the answer of a unlinear eqution，My code is like this；

```
library(nleqslv)
fs1<-function(x){
  y<-numeric(length(x))
  q<-x[1]
  f<-x[2]
  tau=0.2;epsilon=9;t=1.2;gamma=0.3;w=0.5;eta=0.95;lambda=1.2
  k1=q^(-epsilon)/(f*(q^(1-epsilon))+(1-f)*t^(1-epsilon))
  k2=t*(t*q)^(-epsilon)/(f*(t*q)^(1-epsilon)+1-f)
  k3=q*f*(1-tau)+lambda*tau*f*(q*f+1-f)/(lambda*f+1-f)
  k4=(1-f)*(1-tau)+tau*(1-f)*(q*f+1-f)/(lambda*f+1-f)
  kv1=(q^(1-gamma))*((f/(1-f))^(-gamma+w*(1-eta)))
  kv2=((f*((t*q)^(1-epsilon))+1-f)/(f*(q^(1-epsilon))+(1-f)*(t^(1-epsilon))))^((w+1-gamma)/(1-epsilon))
  kv3=((q*gamma*(1-tau)*(lambda*f+1-f)+lambda*tau*(q*f+1-f))/(gamma*(1-tau)*(lambda*f+1-f)+tau*(q*f+1-f)))^w
  y[1]=k1*k3+k2*k4-1
  y[2]=kv1*kv2*kv3-1
  y
}
startx<-c(0.6,1.1)
result<-nleqslv(startx,fs1,control = list(allowSingular=T))
```

But the error  comes as like following:

```
Error in nleqslv(startx, fs1, control = list(allowSingular = T)) : 
  initial value of fn function contains non-finite values (starting at index=2)
  Check initial x and/or correctness of function
```

How should I do next?Thanks for your answer!

Comment: off topic: its called nonlinear instead of unlinear

Comment: When I run `fs1(startx)` I get: [1] -0.1520587        NaN, so the error message seems accurate.

Comment: ok  thank you.But how I can sovle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem by looking at the starting value for your function.
In your function you have an expression `(f/(1-f))^gamma`. `f` comes from `x[2]`; it is `1.1` at the start. Plugging that into the expression given above yields NaN.

So your starting values are incorrect.
You need starting values for `x[2]` between 0 and 1.

So do it like so:

```
startx <- c(.5,.5)
result<-nleqslv(startx,fs1,control = list(allowSingular=TRUE))
result
```

with this result

```
$x
[1] 1.0148741 0.5609061

$fvec
[1] -1.323552e-10 -6.190382e-12

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 18

$njcnt
[1] 1

$iter
[1] 13
```

Finally some remarks on your code:

Please use `TRUE` instead of `T` to avoid confusion.
Please use `<-` in assignments in your function code.
And use more spaces. Your function code is unreadable.